# Prove that field $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x,3)$ is isomorphic to field $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: ring-isomorphism

I don't realize what to do. Could you give me some hints or point to solution?

I tried to construct surjective homomorphism with $Ker(\phi)=(x, 3)$ by intuition to use First Isomorphism Theorem for Rings, but couldn't find such.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x,3)$ ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR , I didn't understand a meaning of the question.

Comment: I mean are you sure about $\mathbb{Z}[x](x,3)$ ? I think it should be the quotient ring  $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x,3)$ by the ideal $(x,3)$ .

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR , oh didn't notice this typo. Yeah, you are right, I ment $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x,3)$, thank you. Already edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You know such a homomorphism should send $x$ to $0$ (because $x$ is in the kernel), and $1$ to $1$ (because $1$ is not in the kernel, and there is no other way to make $\phi(1)^2=\phi(1)$). There aren't many choices left after that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use the third isomorphism theorem as follows: 
$$ \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x,3) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x))/((x,3)/(x)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(3) \cong \mathbb{Z}_3.$$ Here $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $(x,3)/(x) \cong (3)$.